# PhoneGap, XCode and .app file

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

A client wants me to modify an iPhone app developed in PhoneGap. He sent me .app file. Using package info, I see all of the files making the .app

I installed the phonegap plugin for XCode.

My question is how do I import the .app file in Xcode or should it be modified outside of Xcode using HTML editors and then built for IOS with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the www folder inside the app file and import it into your phonegap project.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Any recommendations on best tool to edit the html, js and css?

Comment: I always used Eclipse Juno(which supports everything) before porting my app to XCode. But there must be some add on's for xcode for JS and HTML ?